# Convert a tuple into Datetime

Tags: python, datetime, tuples

Kindly need some help please :)

I have two date-time's i am using the date-time.combine to concatenate 
one is datetime.date (pretty much todays date) - the other is datetime.time (which is a manually defined time) keep getting stuck with the below error;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sunsetTimer.py", line 167, in <module>
    if currentTime >= lightOffDT:
TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to tuple
```

Rather new at Python, so probably a really stupid question.
have tried pulling from the tuple with lightOffDT[0] - but get an error that an integer is required. 
when I print, it prints as a normal date-time e.g 2019-07-29 23:30:00

```
todayDate = datetime.date.today()
off1 =  datetime.time(23,30,0)
lightOffDT = datetime.datetime.combine(todayDate,off1)

currentTime >= lightOffDT: #currentTime is today (datetime)
```

I would like to compare the combined date-time so I can compare to the current date and time.

currentTime is calculated as:

```
import tzlocal
local_timezone = tzlocal.get_localzone()
currentTime = datetime.datetime.now(local_timezone)
```

TOTAL CODE; - This is on a Raspberry pi.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from time import localtime, strftime
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import datetime 
import ephem
import pytz
import sys
import tzlocal


Mon = 0
Tue = 1
Wed = 2
Thu = 3
Fri = 4
Sat = 5
Sun = 6



Pin11 = 11  # pin11
Pin12 = 12  # pin12

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)  # Numbers GPIOs by physical location
GPIO.setup(Pin11, GPIO.OUT)  # Set LedPin 11 mode is output / deck lights
GPIO.setup(Pin12, GPIO.OUT)  # Set LedPin 11 mode is output / path lights

SEC30 = timedelta(seconds=30)

home = ephem.Observer()
# replace lat, long, and elevation to yours
home.lat = '-37.076732'
home.long = '174.939366'
home.elevation = 5
local_timezone = tzlocal.get_localzone() # Gets time zone Pacific/Auckland

sun = ephem.Sun()
sun.compute(home)

fmt = "%d-%b-%Y %H%MUTC"


#Weekend timers
#def lightonTimes_weekend():
   #on1 = set via sunsettime
   #on2 = datetime.time(04,30,00)

def lightoffTimes_Deviate():
   off1 =  datetime.time(23,30,0)
   return off1

# Weekday timers    
def lightonTimes_Normal():
   #on1 = set via sunsettime
   on2 = datetime.time(4,30,0)
   return on2

def lightoffTimes_Normal():
    off1 = datetime.time(22,30,0)
    off2 = datetime.time(5,30,0)
    return off1, off2

def dateTimeTomorrow():
    tomorrowDate = datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    return tomorrowDate


def localtimesTZ():
    currentTime = datetime.datetime.now(local_timezone) # Current New Zealand TimeZones.
    todayDate = datetime.date.today()
    tday = todayDate.weekday()
    return currentTime, tday, todayDate

#def ephemtimes_Tomorrow():    



def ephemtimes():
    #sun.compute(home)

    nextrise = home.next_rising(sun)
    nextset = home.previous_setting(sun)

    nextriseutc= nextrise.datetime() + SEC30
    nextsetutc= nextset.datetime() + SEC30

    sunrise = nextriseutc.replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc).astimezone(local_timezone)
    sunset = nextsetutc.replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc).astimezone(local_timezone)

    sunriseTime = sunrise.time()
    sunsetTime = sunset.time()

    #print "Sunrise local ", sunrise
    #print "Sunset local ", sunset
    #print "Current time ", currentTime

    #print "Local Time: ", local_timezone
    #print "next sunrise: ", nextriseutc.strftime(fmt)
    #print "next sunset:  ", nextsetutc.strftime(fmt)

    return sunrise, sunriseTime, sunset, sunsetTime



if __name__ == '__main__':

    sunrise, sunriseTime, sunset, sunsetTime = ephemtimes() # calls times function to pull sunrise, sunset times.
    currentTime, tday, todayDate =  localtimesTZ()



    #print "Current Time " + str(currentTime)
    #print todayDate
    #print sunrise
    #print "Sunset time " + str(sunset)
    #print sunriseTime
    #print sunsetTime
    #print tday

    tomorrowDate = dateTimeTomorrow()
    #print tomorrowDate


    # start loop here
    #off1 >= lightoffTimes_Deviate()


    if (tday == Sun) or (tday == Mon): # timer for weekend (Sunday or Monday)

        #CurrentTime & SunSet time are in full datetime - converted to Local Time
        if currentTime > sunset:
            GPIO.output(Pin11, GPIO.LOW)  # Turn GPIO pins on
            GPIO.output(Pin12, GPIO.LOW)
            # ***********************************
            off1 = lightoffTimes_Deviate()  #get off time


            print 'error below'
            print todayDate
            print off1




            #### this is where the problems start!!!
            lightOffDT = datetime.datetime.combine(todayDate,off1)


            print lightOffDT



            #print "light off time " + str(lightoffdatetime)

            while True:



                currentTime =  localtimesTZ()


                if currentTime >= lightOffDT:
                    GPIO.output(Pin11, GPIO.HIGH)  # Turn GPIO pins on
                    GPIO.output(Pin12, GPIO.HIGH)
                    break
                else:
                    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear') 
                    print "Current Time " + str(lightoffdatetimepython)
                    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: But what is `currentTime`? Show how you defined it.

Comment: currentTime ; (using tzlocal)
    local_timezone = tzlocal.get_localzone()
    currentTime = datetime.datetime.now(local_timezone)

im using the currentTime earlier in the code to compare to another datetime. works fine?

Comment: You must have redefined one or the other of these somewhere. Please edit the question to show your complete code.

Comment: Hey mate, added whole code.

Comment: What is the output of `print(lightOffDT)` and `print(currentTime)`?

Comment: Hey Nick, 
currentTime = 2019-07-29 22:38:37.003206+12:00
lightOffDT = 2019-07-29 23:30:00

Answer (score 1):

Look at how you have defined `currentTime`:

```
currentTime =  localtimesTZ()
```

Your `localtimesTZ()` actually returns a tuple `currentTime, tday, todayDate`, which is what is assigned to `currentTime`.
Not sure why you are doing that; returning just the `currentTime` should be sufficient, since it is a `datetime.datetime` object.

Then you try and compare that tuple to `lightOffDT`, which is a `datetime.datetime` object. Hence the error.

You could try:

```
if currentTime[0] >= lightOffDT:
```

That would actually compare two `datetime.datetime` objects.

Comment: I think I did that as I needed timezone aware times. get the below error with the changes above made. - i am new with Python. so maybe doing something really backward.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sunsetTimer.py", line 170, in <module>
    if currentTime[0] >= lightOffDT:
TypeError: can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes

Comment: ah, got it to work. thank you! relised i didnt need to keep comparing to the timezone time. just pulled the currentTime directly - works now :) thank you everyone. 
i was caught up thinking its the combine causing the issue

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are just trying to do a simple comparison of a manually set date and check if that day is today. If that is the case it would be simpler to use the same class datetime. Below is a simple example checking if today (manually defined) is today (defined by python)

from datetime import datetime

```
todayDate = datetime.today()
someOtherDate = datetime(year=2019,month=7,day=29)

if todayDate.date() == someOtherTime.date():
    print(True)
```

outputs

```
True
```

Comment: Hello, 
Im comparing a date (which is either going to be today, or tomorrow. 
then combining with a manually defined time - Which will be triggered twice a day  - one at 4:30am, next at (depending on sunset time)

Answer (score 0):

i think you are trying to compare a datetime with a tuple.

This is the line that adds `currentTime` to a tuple:

```
currentTime, tday, todayDate =  localtimesTZ()
```

You therefore need the index of `currentTime` from the tuple for comparison i.e

```
if currentTime[0] >= lightOffDT
```

Index is 0 because currentTime is the first item in the tuple.